# Flyway migrations aren't always executed without recognizeable pattern

Tags: java, flyway

I have a project with two modules. Both modules use flyway for migration and initial setup of the database. Both projects are independent. I also have a test in each module. Whenever I run both modules, or also only one test from one module the migration may not be executed. 
Module one contains

- a.b.c.account.persistence.jdbc.migrations.Vaccount_1__CreateStructure.java
  a.b.c.account.persistence.jdbc.migrations.Vaccount_2__CreateIndexOnName.sql
  ...
  a.b.c.account.persistence.jdbc.migrations.Vaccount_5__AddDAOCreatedAndUpdated.sql

and JDBCAccountPersistenceServiceImpl with JDBCAccountPersistenceServiceImplTest.

Module two contains

- a.b.c.authentication.persistence.jdbc.migrations.Vauth_1__CreateTableForPasswords.sql
  a.b.c.authentication.persistence.jdbc.JDBCAuthenticationPersistenceServiceImpl

and JDBCAuthenticationPersistenceServiceImplTest.

Both Impls share a parent class the calls in its init method:

```
//prepare db.
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(getDataSource());
flyway.setLocations(getClass().getPackage().getName()+".migrations");
flyway.migrate();
```

Both tests work if started separately on clean db and on filled db. However, If I clean DB and run the tests from intellij with running JDBCAuthenticationPersistenceServiceImplTest first, the other test would fail:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "account" does not exist
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
```

The schema_version would in this case contain only one line:

```
1 |              1 | auth.1  | CreateTableForPasswords | SQL  | Vauth_1__CreateTableForPasswords.sql | -1961897674 | another      | 2013-01-14 23:39:00.736033 |             18 | t
```

If i delete all tables manually the test would run again. If I run the test from console on clean db (maven) it also works.
What am I doing wrong?
could it be that auth.1 is considered higher version than account.1 and therefore account.1 patch isn't executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three issues at hand here.

1. You are missing a sqlMigrationPrefix like Vaccount_
2. Flyway is overly permissive with versions and should reject account.1 as a valid version number
3. The modules should probably have separate metadata tables

Comment: Hello Axel,
1 and 2) i was actually thinking it was a good idea to add a prefix to the version so I can separate different modules. account and auth are different modules that can but must not end in the same db. Therefor I would like them to have independent version ranges. This way each module would have own versions - 
a.1 a.2 a.3
b.1 b.2 
That would keep versions independent and allow the flexibility to use separate db per module in prod environment, but one db for all modules in dev/test environment.
3) probably you are right, how do I achieve that? ;-)